# Joomla xcache authentication error

Tags: php, authentication, joomla, xcache

I am using Joomla for my website administration and appeared to have encountered an error while configuring cache settings. I accidentially set GUI option from file to xcache and now everytime I try to do something a dialog box appears requiring my authentication but when I enter it nothing happens and it doesn't save my settings. How can I change the setting back to "file"? I don't really have my FTP cocnfigured yet and when I tried to do so, this xcache box appeared again and disabled me from saving my ftp settings. Is there any other way to get to php.conf file where I could change that manually? There has to be one.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting plan should have a basic file manager in it's control panel — e.g. if your host uses WHM/cPanel in the cPanel interface there is a "File Manager" icon. It will be in the Files group which looks like this:

[image: cPanel Files Group]

After opening the File Manager you should navigate to your websites root directly and you should be able to see a file called `configuration.php`.

Edit this file and change the line that defines the `$cache_handler` so that it has `file` in the value. Before you save it the line should look like this:

```
public $cache_handler = 'file';
```

Take care not to change anything else in the file as you could cause other issues.

If you're not sure or feel unsure of doing this you should probably get your hosting providers support to change the file for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. As I was given the admin account, they didn't actually give me the server access. I realized that just yesterday.  Thanks for help.

Comment: there is no way to change it directly, using just joomla admin console right?